# In a RESTful Spring Boot application, how do I do url queries of nested object properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Here, we are using the following classes, `Customer` and `Address`. Assume getters and setters are implemented, and the constructors fill all fields except for the automatically filled `id`:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    @OneToOne
    private Address address;
    /** ... */
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;
    /** ... */
}
```

Notice how the field `state` is nested inside of the `Address` instance object inside of the `Customer` class.

Now our project implements the `JpaRepository<Customer, Long>` interface in order to handle all queries, and said interface includes a `findAll` function that takes an `Example<Customer>` and searches the database according to that example. So we set up our handler

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getCustomers(@Valid Customer customer) {
    /** call to customerRepository.findAll(Example.of(customer)) inside here */
}
```

Now in our RESTful application, we type in the URL `/customers?state=IL`, expecting the `customer` argument to be fed

`new Customer(null, null, new Address(null, null, "IL", null))`

but instead, it is fed

`new Customer(null, null, null)`

Why is that, and what do we have to do to make sure the first object is passed instead of the second?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is to use the @Embedded and @Embeddable
annotations.

---

```
@Entity
public class Customer{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String email;
@Embedded
private Address address;
}


@Entity
@Embeddable 
public class Address{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zipCode
}
```

---

This will solve your problem, @Embedded will embed Address into Customer Entity hence solve your problem.

Comment: you might as well need to remove @Entity in Address Entity, this will work fine for you

Comment: The RESTController is still passing a null address object.

Comment: please contact me on my email tapsshore@gmail.com we might need to see the full code and address the issue

Comment: Thank you, but I realized it wasn't working because I didn't use dot notation in the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ‘@Valid Customer customer’ and when you did ‘/customers?state=IL’no Adress instance will be created automatically.

Because your request wait for a body. Here if you want init a address you should put @param(´state’) String state and instanciate manually.